# How to automatically forward class instance methods to another object's methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aggregation, subclassing, forwarding

Regarding the following example code, is there any type-safe way of automatically forwarding any of the prototypal method calls, each to its related method of another object?

```
class Foo {
  greet() {
    return "hello";
  }
  sayGoodbye() {
    return "bye";
  }

  // ... many more methods
}

class Bar {
  foo: Foo;

  constructor() {
    this.foo = new Foo();
  }

  greet() {
    this.foo.greet();
  }

  sayGoodbye() {
    this.foo.sayGoodbye();
  }

  // ...
}
```

We don't have to write `method() { foo.method() }` for all methods on `Foo`? I.e. something like how in JavaScript we could do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo.prototype).forEach(...)` and point the methods to `foo`, but in a type-safe way?

I've tried mixins but I find those hard to work with since those invert the relationship (`Foo` has to subclass `Bar`, so I can't e.g. instantiate `Foo` with specific parameters when declaring `Bar`).

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo.prototype).forEach(...)` is a totally type-safe approach for implementing forwarding, based on an aggregated property, in a generic way. Or do you mean, you are looking for a TypeScript yoga/gymnastics-figure which is capable of expressing such a pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) keyword to create a subclass which inherits from its [superclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super):

> The extends keyword is used in [class declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) or [class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) to create a class that is a child of another class.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHMBOBTXALgBQCUK6G0eBArtgHbQBEAFriCPEwNwUC+FCGACeAcUQATAEbDcpcpSqE6jJjNw9+qAalCQYAITDZouAB4Fc9CTARJkAgPSPFigHofPb1Lvj0IBNBSxtAAvND0uADu0EbYpLy+-vAguAB0nJhEwdhpOPjEJCTc0M7MbBxcSRAp6ZnZxmlCYpLqpMWlLmqyTKhAA)

```js
class Foo {
  greet() {
    return "hello";
  }
  sayGoodbye() {
    return "bye";
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}
//        ^^^^^^^

const bar = new Bar();

console.log(bar.greet()); // "hello"
console.log(bar.sayGoodbye()); // "bye"
```